# Setting a new user inactive based on group -- Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently busy with my user app and trying to achieve a way to add new users to different pre-defined groups. My sign_up view for one of the groups is as follows:

```
def signup_view_zakelijk(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='zakelijk')
            user.groups.add(group)
            return redirect('user:login')
        return render(request, 'user/signup.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'user/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

The group is assigned after the save form.save so i made a post_save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_zakelijk_inactive(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    group = Group.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
    print(group)
    if group == 'zakelijk':
        if instance._state.adding is True:
            instance.is_active = False
        else:
            return
    else:
        return
```

I've set the print statement to check if the user group names got printed and this works. But the new added user is not inactive by default. When I erase the if group == 'zakelijk' conditional the signal works properly but is also executed for other user groups (so every new user is inactive by default - only need this for the group 'zakelijk'.

The Signal code that works properly:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def user_zakelijk_inactive(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance._state.adding is True:
        instance.is_active = False
    else:
        return
```

Does anyone have some ideas to addin the conditional?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're trying to do things in python that Django / the database can do for you. Secondly - you don't save:

```
# Only check if a group exists that is named "zakelijk"
if instance.groups.filter(name='zakelijk').exists():
    instance.is_active = False
    # One could use update_fields=['is_active'], but in practice
    # user instances are not big entities.
    instance.save()
```

For details see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists). Since `Group.name` is a unique field, this comparable in performance to the primary key lookup in the examples.

Comment: Thank you. Removed the Reciever and build the function within my view. Works appropriately right now!

Answer (score 0):

Because, you were comparing with list, I think you were not passing from if statement. I think it should work:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_zakelijk_inactive(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    group = instance.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
    print(group)
    if 'zakelijk' in group:
        if instance._state.adding is True:
            instance.is_active = False
        else:
            return
    else:
        return
```

Comment: Tried this but it still keeps the new user with 'zakelijk' active. Changed the post_save to pre_save and this is setting the user to inactive by default but does not check for the zakelijk parameter. The pre_save method can't access the group name because it is referenced after the save method in my sing_up view.. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Add to the above answer: the conditional now checks if the name 'zakelijk' is within the group and this returns True because it is. But when i register a User with for example 'employee' the 'zakelijk' is still in the group so it is True as well.